# Small random rectangles on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I started to get one or more small garbled rectangles on various windows in Windows 7. They disappear / change place when a window is redrawn. Any idea what this could be? I am not 100% sure, but it seems that I do not get this bug unless I open Facebook on Firefox.

[image: Example]

Laptop model: HP ProBook 4720
Graphics card: ATI Radeon HD 6370

Comment: Did this start happening after a recent graphics driver update? If not seems like a failing graphics card.

Comment: @Karan even without updating the graphics drivers, drivers can still fail, so a reinstall of the graphicscard drivers is always the first thing one should do, but yeah, if that doesn't resolve it, its likely failing hardware.

Comment: @LPChip: Yes existing drivers can fail, but in general when something strange starts happening soon after updating the driver then obviously the new driver is suspect. That's why I wanted the OP to confirm.

Comment: OP might not be aware of a driverupdate, as its possible to update graphics drivers through windows update too as optional updates.

Comment: Thank you. Device manager shows 2010.08.05 as the driver date, so it does not seem like there was an automatic update. I will try to update it.

Comment: No, updating the driver did not help. It is funny that these rectangles are not so frequent, but I can reproduce them easiest when I open Facebook on Firefox.

Comment: Try putting your CPU and GPU under some stress (play a 3D game or use benchmarking software). If artifacts become more frequent or more apparent then you might have hardware problem (broken solder joint or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been experiencing a similar problem on Firefox recently. Black (bigger than yours) rectangles, some parts not refreshing correctly, etc...

**Try disabling hardware acceleration and see if it fixes the problem:** Hamburger menu > Options > Advanced > General > Untick *Use hardware acceleration when available.*

I was also experiencing some Youtube glitches with hardware acceleration. Disabling it fixed the problem. But may cause performance drops or even increases on certain configurations.

Also you may have bad/old drivers. Try updating your graphic card drivers.

Comment: Yes, this appears to fix my problem. I'm just wondering if this is Firefox software bug or a hardware problem, because the graphics driver update didn't help.

Comment: I'm not sure. You and me might be victims of the same situations that's causing the problem. But I've seen this asked several times on web. And this haven't happened on other browsers.

Comment: What's your GPU?

Comment: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6370